# Simple, universal Makefile

Tags: makefile

I've tried to create my own, small but universal Makefile for my university projects. What I managed to write is flowing code. The problem is, I have to run `make all` multiple times to compile all executables. The `.o` files and corresponding executables are created incrementally on every `make` call and not at once. How should it be done right?

```
# Variables
Project = Project_Name
Src     = src
Include = inc
Lib     = lib
Build   = build
Dist    = dist
Res     = resources
LibSem  = -L$(Lib) -lbib
CC      = gcc $(CFLAGS)

# Vpaths for implicite rules.
vpath %.c $(Src)
vpath %.h $(Include)
vpath %.o $(Build)
vpath %.d $(Build)
# Src is set for explicite named files.
CPPFLAGS += -I$(Src) -I$(Include)

# Define Source variable with the list of .c files
# File is updated by Vim by the call of "make update"
include build/Sources.inc

all: prog1 prog2
    cp -fr $(Res)/* $(Dist)

bib: libbib.o
    ar -cvrs $(Lib)/libbib.a $^

prog1: prog1.o sem
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(Dist)/$@ $< $(LibSem)

prog2: prog2.o sem
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(Dist)/$@ $< $(LibSem)

update:
    #----------------------------------------
    # Updating list of sources.
    #----------------------------------------
    echo -n "Sources = " > $(Build)/Sources.inc
    find src/ -type f -name '*.c' -printf "%f " >> $(Build)/Sources.inc

clean:
    #----------------------------------------
    # Cleaning files.
    #----------------------------------------
    rm -rf $(Build)/*
    rm -rf $(Dist)/*
    rm -rf $(Lib)/*
    touch $(Build)/Sources.inc

dist: clean dep all
    #----------------------------------------
    # Distribute archive.
    #----------------------------------------
    tar -cvzf $(Project).tar.gz $(Include) $(Res) $(Src) Makefile

# changed for output in Build directory
%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) -o $(Build)/$@ $<

# autogenerated dependencies files
-include $(subst .c,.d,$(Sources))

dep %.d: %.c
    #----------------------------------------
    # Generating auto-dependencies
    #----------------------------------------
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $(Build)/$@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $(Build)/$@.$$$$ > $(Build)/$@; \
    rm -f $(Build)/$@.$$$$
```

Comment: see this [project](https://github.com/deminets/unimake)

Answer (score 0):

These rules are wrong:

```
prog1: prog1.o sem
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(Dist)/$@ $< $(LibSem)
```

Every "normal" rule in make *must* update the target you told make it would update.  Here your rule tells make it will update the file `prog1`, but what your rule actually does is update the file `dist/prog1`.  Those are completely different and your makefile does not work because you've lied to make.

In general it's not possible to use `vpath` to describe where to put generated targets.  The `vpath` feature is only valid when used to locate *source* files.

You'll have to write your rule like this:

```
$(Dist)/prog1: $(Build)/prog1.o sem
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LibSem)
```

However that's just the tip of the iceberg.  You'll need to make a lot more changes as a result of this to get things the way you want.